# Clear Cell if Cell Contains Text VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Need help with clearing contents of a cell if a cell contains 2 specific texts:

This is my formula:

```
For p = lrow To 2 Step -1
    
    If ws3.Cells(p, 10).Value = "Carrier is disabled" Or ws3.Cells(p, 10).Value = "No Error Message" Then
        ws.Cells(p, 10).ClearContents
    End If

Next p
```

Not working at the moment :D

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `learcontents` has a incorrect worksheet name. Assuming everything else not shown here is correct, change...

```
ws.Cells(p, 10).ClearContents
```

to

```
ws3.Cells(p, 10).ClearContents
```